# How can I transfer files from one application to another in the same iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am writing an iOS application that performs conversion of a file saved by another application on the same device to another format. How can I transfer files from one application to another in the same device? Note that the files are non-textual files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`UIDocumentInteractionController` is your friend.

Basically it works like this:

1. App 1 registers as being able to handle files of type XYZ
2. App 2 implements `UIDocumentInteractionController` and will give users the options to "send the file to App1" (I believe this has to be user activated)
3. App 1 implements `-(BOOL)application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` and deals with the transferred file which will be saved in your `Documents/Inbox` directory. From there you can copy the file elsewhere and then manipulated it, making sure you clean up by getting rid of the original one saved on the Inbox folder.

Class reference available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Document interaction programming guide available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403)

Comment: So this means that App1 will only be able to access the file if and only if App2 allows it but not the other way round (the way windows OS operates). Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct, the file can only be sent to app1, app1 cannot pull it from app2. BUT in saying that, you could try registering a custom URI scheme that allows app1 to "request" something from app2 and get app2 to respond to it accordingly. This is only theory though, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: is it possible to send multiple files? - like selecting multiple photos to be attached to EMail in standard photos app.

Comment: @rog Can I get the sample code or example to receive and transfer audio files? I am stuck at this point. Could you please take a look at my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697612/xamarin-ios-share-receive-audio-file

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing both apps, you can store shared information in the keychain as long as your bundle identifiers conform to the same bundle seed id. See [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html) for more info. Of course, if you are making both applications, you can use a URL scheme to pass in base64 encoded data as well.

Update: As rog said below, UIDocumentInteractionController is great, but it is only available for 4.2 and up, so you are cutting out a major portion of your users if you want to use it.