# iOS shared file

Tags: iphone, ios, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I transfer files from one application to another in the same iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034942/how-can-i-transfer-files-from-one-application-to-another-in-the-same-ios-device)

I have a file in an app downloaded from the network to the app's documents directory. I would like to open this file in another app (using a custom url scheme).

I am running into a permissions issue since apps are sandboxed and other applications can't see the file in my app's documents directory.

Where can I put the file so that other applications can read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this as you explained.

What you need to do is set up your application to "accept" certain types of files. To do this you "register" you application as a possible receiver of for example PDF files.

Check out this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

You should check out the UIDocumentInteractionController class.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I didn't write the app that is receiving the file. It supports a custom url scheme, but doesn't "accept" any special document types. Is there a way to transfer files using the url mechanism or is that impossible?