# Access files of one Application from other application in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

Can we have shared storage in iPhone which is accessible to other ios apps?

I am working on one ios app which downloads updated files from server. And there will be some other application which uses those files. So for that I want to save downloaded files on particular location. So that I can access those files from other application.

So the flow will be like this,

Application1, which will download files from server.

And

Application2 or Application3..... will use those files.

Do we have such type of shared location in iOS. Is it possible in iOS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034942/how-can-i-transfer-files-from-one-application-to-another-in-the-same-ios-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read Apple Doc [File System Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Answer (score 6):

No. Its not possible as your application will be in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "share" files between in iOS, because all apps are sandboxed and can't access other files besides its own files with the public APIs.

Answer (score 3):

All applications are sandboxed as the other answers have said.

However, if you own both apps, or you know the developer of the other app, you could always use some sort of cloud storage, but that may defeat the point of you asking this question

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could combine the functionality of all the separate apps into a single app.  Have each one be a module accessible from a master menu.