# How to establish app to app communicaiton using socket on same device in iPhone without any server component?

Tags: iphone, sockets, service

I want my app to intercommunicate with my service,send and receive data to and from service

Comment: have you tried anything in terms of code?

Comment: I used url schemes for inter app communication,but by using this,and calling app 2 from app 1,opens app 2 on main thread.I want just to send a kind of notification from one app(app 1) to other(app 2) and keep main app(app 1) working on main thread and app 2 on background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

- [How can I transfer files from one application to another in the same iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034942/how-can-i-transfer-files-from-one-application-to-another-in-the-same-ios-device)
- [UIDocumentInteractionController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDocumentInteractionController)

Hope this might help to achieve your goal

Comment: Thanks this was quite helpful,but in my case i want two app to intercommunicate by sending and receiving data.One of my app is like background polling,which send data to my other app

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of references about that'll help you with what you're trying to achieve, I'd recommend doing a little research and attempting to get something basic working.

To get any help, you'll need to provide a bit more information - what protocol does your service operate on? what is the function of the app? what have you tried?

This place is an invaluable resource to programmers who ask for help, rather than an entire solution. :)

Good Luck!