# open file from local file system with default application iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have downloaded some files from server and stored into local file system. I want to open them with default application in the device. How can I open files with default application. Please provide some sample code.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I transfer files from one application to another in the same iOS device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034942/how-can-i-transfer-files-from-one-application-to-another-in-the-same-ios-device)

Comment: UIDocumentInteractionController is great for when you wish to present the user with available options, however the OP asked for opening file with 'default application'. Eg: an html file will open with mobile safari automatically, and not present the user with other web browser apps, that have also registered for that UTI type. @Darren

Comment: ok when I use UIdocumentInterationController,it throws error as "launch services unable to find app identifier com.apple.mobilemail"

Comment: what file types are you wanting default application to open specifically? @user2634244

Comment: I am using gif, tif, png and text. But I am using them in simulator. I need to ask onething, what is UTI of UIDocumentInteractionController? Do I neeed to specify the UTI, is it mandatory?

Comment: For a complete explanation on UTI's read the Uniform Type Identifiers Overview [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) You shouldn't need to specify UTI for these file types. See my edit to the answer I posted. @user2634244

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to represent the **resource** (*downloaded file to be opened*) with an NSURL object.
The following assumes an NSString named filePath that is already initialised with the path to the **resource** to open.

```
NSURL *resourceToOpen = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Then it's best to check first that there is an app that will open the resource.

```
BOOL canOpenResource = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:resourceToOpen];
```

Finally if the above line returns yes then open the resource.

```
if (canOpenResource) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:resourceToOpen]; }
```

I quote the following from UIApplication class reference with respect to the instance method canOpenURL:

> This method guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another app will be launched to handle it. It does not guarantee that the full URL is valid.

However, if your wish to present the user with a list of apps that have registered with the appropriate UTI for that file type you can do something like this-

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
documentController.delegate = self;
[documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

You must implement the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate protocol. Also for known file types the system should resolve the correct assignment of the UTI property without setting it.

Comment: Hard to say but probably not. Main reason being the simulator has a limited repertoire of apps compared to an actual device. The only app I can see of any interest is the photos app. I would test with a png file on sim and see if you get a nibble, but my advice is to test this sort of thing on an actual device and avoid the sim completely.

Comment: Ok thanks, I tested some other samples also the preview is opening correctly but, actual document is not opening in simulator.