# Handle local files in default iOS application

Tags: ios, file, default

I have files that are stored in the Document directory. The url scheme for them is `file:///` and so on. Is there a way to handle such files with appropriate default app. Lets say I have a video file there and instead of handling play in my app, it opens in the default iOS app for video playback. Or maybe I have a doc file and it should open in MS Word if it is installed.

What I tried is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869815/open-file-from-local-file-system-with-default-application-ios). It did not work. I believe the `openURL` method depends on the URL scheme which is always `file:///` in this case. Even if I know what type of file it is, how do I go about opening it in default outside application.

Comment: I am sure this isn't the first time this has been asked.  Have you searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was use `UIDocumentInteractionController`.
You can preview and choose to open in other app. Or you can just open.
It works for documents, video and probably audio(not tested) files. The preview player for the video is not that great.
For a demo [tuts.plus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130).